# alfresco template of managing document of work process

Tags: alfresco

In most cases, work of creating document belongs to a specific process.And each document has the context of input and output with each other.This means that if all the document of a process is not completed, work of the next process cannot be started and its document cannot be created.For example, in process of development, the process of detail design can be started only after the process of basic design is completed.

In alfresco,I can define fix directory structure as space template and I can create directory using that template.But I cannot define order of work process and I have no more knowledge.
let me know how to implement or customize?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Do you want to create Workflows for this? Or directory structures? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You may have the directory structure created, but you probably need some workflows defined. Workflows will basically do what you need: when one user creates a document and finishes his part of the process, he can mark his part of the work done and pass it to the next step.

You can learn some basics about workflows on [Alfresco wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Workflow), of course.
I suggest that you take a look and read the documents at the [Custom Workflow Guide](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/WorkflowAdministration) and maybe [this](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/WorkflowTraining) material.
After that, if you don't understand much, take a look at the [samples](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/WorkflowSamples), then try modifying one of the samples and eventually design your own workflow.